# can't connect to mqtt broker via ssl

Tags: java, linux, ssl, mqtt

I have a raspberry running a mqtt broker and a java backend. I can't establish a connection from backend to broker since I've implemented ssl. I can connect the backend to the broker on raspberry from my IDE running on my MacBook like:

```
client = new MqttAsyncClient(
            "ssl://my-domain.com:1883", "backend");
```

if the backend is on the raspberry I tried:

```
client = new MqttAsyncClient(
            "ssl://localhost:1883", "backend");


client = new MqttAsyncClient(
            "ssl://127.0.0.1:1883", "backend");
```

No success. I´ve never used a ssl connection in this context. did I oversee something?

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" No connection to client (32104)
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ExceptionHelper.createMqttException(ExceptionHelper.java:31)
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ClientComms.sendNoWait(ClientComms.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttAsyncClient.subscribe(MqttAsyncClient.java:721)
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttAsyncClient.subscribe(MqttAsyncClient.java:681)
    at com.cdh.Service.mqttManager.subscribe(mqttManager.java:243)
    at com.cdh.main.main(main.java:14)
```

EDIT:

I changed the port to 8883. It works if I run the backend on an other device but not if the broker and the backend are on the raspberry. I also tried to use the domain name from my cert.

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65942596/edit) the question to show any errors you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

The hostname you use to connect needs to match the CN or SAN entries in the certificate presented by the broker or else it will fail validation.

Unless you included `127.0.0.1` or `localhost` in the certificate the the client will reject the connection because the certificate doesn't validate for that address.

p.s. you should probably use a different port for MQTT of TLS rather than 1883 as that is the standard port for MQTT without TLS.

Comment: thx. I changed the port to 8883. "ssl://my-domain.com:8883" won't work either. again only If I run the backend on another device.

Comment: FYI: there is no scheme like ssl. With 8883 port, it would look like: "mqtts://my-domain.com:8883".

Comment: @SharifMamun `ssl://` is a perfectly valid schema for some MQTT clients (e.g. in this case the Paho Java client https://www.eclipse.org/paho/files/javadoc/org/eclipse/paho/client/mqttv3/MqttClient.html#MqttClient-java.lang.String-java.lang.String- )

Comment: Thanks @hardillb! Never worked with any Java clients, little knowledge!